# R - tidy augment confidence interval

Tags: r, ggplot2, broom

I am wondering how I can compute confidence interval using the `broom` package.

What I am trying to do is simple and standard :

```
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(50)
y <- 2.5 + (3 * x) + rnorm(50, mean = 2.5, sd = 2)
dat <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
mod <- lm(y ~ x, data = dat)
```

Using `visreg` I can plot regression models with `CI` very simply with :

```
library(visreg)
visreg(mod, 'x',  overlay=TRUE)
```

[image]

I am interesting in reproducing this using `broom` and `ggplot2`, so far I only achieved this :

```
 library(broom) 

 dt = lm(y ~ x, data = dat) %>% augment(conf.int = TRUE)  
 ggplot(data = dt, aes(x, y, colour = y)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line(data = dt, aes(x, .fitted, colour = .fitted))
```

[image]

The `augment` funciton doesn't compute `conf.int`. Any clue how I can add some `smooth` confidence invervals ?

```
 geom_smooth(data=dt, aes(x, y, ymin=lcl, ymax=ucl), size = 1.5, 
        colour = "red", se = TRUE, stat = "smooth")
```

Comment: Why you don't use `geom_smooth(method="lm")` with your original data frame to add regression line with CI?

Comment: The reason is that I need to add many different lines and do more complicated stuffs, so I was wondering if there was an easy way to plot with `broom`. `geom_smooth(method="lm")` is it complicate when you have many variables and when you want to control which line is plotted ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the `broom` output, you can do something like this:

```
ggplot(data = dt, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=.fitted-1.96*.se.fit, ymax=.fitted+1.96*.se.fit), alpha=0.2) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = y)) + 
  geom_line(aes(x, .fitted, colour = .fitted)) +
  theme_bw()
```

I moved `colour=y` into `geom_point()` because you can't apply a colour aesthetic to `geom_ribbon`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just do this (with your original dataset dat):

```
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x, y, colour = y)) + 
  geom_point(size=2) + geom_smooth(method='lm', se = TRUE) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: what if you are running a multivariate regression and you only want to show one variable ?

Comment: @giacomoV not sure i got you, i guess you are talking about multiple regression (not multivariate regression right), where you have more than one predictors for y, e.g., yet another predictor x1, s.t. y~x+ x1, but in that case the visualization should be a plane instead of a line and you need 3D visualization to show the regression plane and the confindence interval volume around the plane, right?

Comment: in 2D i guess we shall only be interested to show the relationship between the response and a single predictor variable only, keeping the other variables fixed.

Comment: So I try to plot the relationships between `y=x1` in an ols model such as `y = x1 + x2 + x3` where `x2+x3` are control variables (so this is a multivariate model). However, I find very cumbersome to do it in R. I just asked another question about it `http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245294/r-plot-lm-issues-with-multivariate-ols`. Thanks for your advice.